# When I run my code, nothing is returned, yet there are no errors and I called to the methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

I called all the methods so I'm not sure why they won't return anything?

this is my attempt:

```
train_mass = 22680
train_acceleration = 10
bomb_mass = 1

def f_to_c(f_temp):
  c_temp = (f_temp - 32) * 5/9
  return c_temp
f100_in_celsius = f_to_c(100)
def c_to_f(c_temp):
  f_temp = c_temp * (9/5) +32
  return f_temp
c0_in_fahrenheight = c_to_f(0)

def get_force(mass, acceleration):
  return mass*acceleration
train_force = get_force(train_mass, train_acceleration)

def get_energy(mass, c=3*10**8):
  return mass * c**2
bomb_energy = get_energy(bomb_mass)
```

I was expecting the values in the method to be returned but nothing gets returned. Also, there were no errors.

Comment: print(bomb_energy)

Comment: There are four functions in your code, which one does not return? And how did you determine that?

Comment: @YuriGinsburg none of the functions return anything. i tried running each individual one and nothing would return for any of them. pycharm didn't give me an error either, just nothing would return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Python Principles](https://pythonprinciples.com/blog/print-vs-return/):

> ### Print vs. return in Python
>
> Printing and returning are completely different concepts.
>
> `print` is a function you call. Calling `print` will immediately make your
> program write out text for you to see. Use `print` when you want to show
> a value to a human.
>
> `return` is a keyword. When a `return` statement is reached, Python will
> stop the execution of the current function, sending a value out to
> where the function was called. Use `return` when you want to send a
> value from one point in your code to another.
>
> Using `return` changes the flow of the program. Using `print` does not.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, use print statements:

```
train_mass = 22680
train_acceleration = 10
bomb_mass = 1

def f_to_c(f_temp):
  c_temp = (f_temp - 32) * 5/9
  return c_temp

f100_in_celsius = f_to_c(100)
print(f100_in_celsius)

def c_to_f(c_temp):
  f_temp = c_temp * (9/5) +32
  return f_temp

c0_in_fahrenheit = c_to_f(0)
print(c0_in_fahrenheit)

def get_force(mass, acceleration):
  return mass * acceleration

train_force = get_force(train_mass, train_acceleration)
print(train_force)

def get_energy(mass, c=3*10**8):
  return mass * c**2

bomb_energy = get_energy(bomb_mass)
print(bomb_energy)
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help. If this solved your question, please accept the answer. @aaakkkaaa1

Comment: @aaakkkaaa1 You might want to read the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/). Indentation should be done with 4 spaces (not 2). The names of constants should be written in capital letters. And you should define the functions after defining the constants at the beginning of your script. Do not mix function definitions and top-level code.